# Python scrapy returns uncomplete data

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am creating a scraper for web data scraping.
There are 58 pages and each page has 12 products.
The data should be return as 58 x 12 = 696 products title but it return only data of 404 products only. Here is my code

```
import scrapy
from fundrazr.items import FundrazrItem
from datetime import datetime
import re


class Fundrazr(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "my_scraper"

    # First Start Url
    start_urls = ["https://perfumehut.com.pk/shop/"]

    npages = 57

    # This mimics getting the pages using the next button. 
    for i in range(2, npages + 1):
        start_urls.append("https://perfumehut.com.pk/shop/page/"+str(i)+"")
    
    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.xpath("//h3[contains(@class, 'product-title')]/a/@href"):
            # add the scheme, eg http://
            url  = "" + href.extract() 
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents) 
                    
    def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
        item = FundrazrItem()

        # Getting Campaign Title
        item['campaignTitle'] = response.xpath("//h1[contains(@class, 'entry-title')]/text()").extract()

        yield item
```

Its a woocommerce website and first page is

```
https://perfumehut.com.pk/shop/
```

and other pages as pagination

```
https://perfumehut.com.pk/shop/page/2/
https://perfumehut.com.pk/shop/page/3/
and up to 58.
```

I want to know what I did wrong by getting npages ?

Regards

Comment: You would have to check to see if the server is correctly returning the pages (see if there are any pages that aren't with status code 200). Have you also tried to play around with the url parameters? You can greatly reduce the number of pages by increasing the `per_page` parameter. Ex:
https://perfumehut.com.pk/shop/?per_page=500

Answer (score 0):

```
import scrapy
from fundrazr.items import FundrazrItem
from datetime import datetime
import re


class Fundrazr(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "my_scraper"

    # First Start Url
    start_urls = ["https://perfumehut.com.pk/shop/"]
    
    def parse(self, response):
        data = FundrazrItem()
        
        for item in response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'products elements-grid ')]/div[contains(@class, 'product-grid-item product ')]/h3/a"):
            data['campaignTitle'] = item.xpath("./text()").extract_first()

            yield data

        next_page = response.xpath("//ul[@class='page-numbers']/li[last()]/a/@href").extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not very useful. Could you add some explanation about how and why this solves the OP's problem?